# Google +1 button error on android app there was a temporary

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I added google plus one button in my app by this guide
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend

When I press button I see google plus window and after that window receive my google plus account name I receive error with message
"There was a temporary problem with your +1. Please try again"

In the android monitor, I get

```
10-14 19:05:42.466 2107-2470/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
10-14 19:05:42.872 2421-3058/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [162] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 503 for https://www.googleapis.com/pos/v1/plusones/https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.facebook.katana?abtk=&cdx=c89&container=http%3A%2F%2FD1Xfy1LMHWn3O%252FW%252BIyo6pO5l5Yo%253D.apps.googleusercontent.com%2F%3Fpkg%3Dcom.bestvpn.hotvpn%26api_key%3DAIzaSyBa9bgzwtnGchlkux96-c5Q_fi19fE1pEA&source=native%3Aandroid_app
```

answer from link in logcat

```
{
 "kind": "pos#plusones",
 "id": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana",
 "isSetByViewer": false,
 "metadata": {
  "type": "URL",
  "globalCounts": {
   "count": 0.0
  }
 },
 "abtk": ""
}
```

I turned on google plus API in the developer console four hours ago.

Can someone help me, please? Maybe I forget to check API anywhere. Checked in the google-services.json
Maybe it's because I'm testing it from emulator. Can't test in real device now

Comment: Don't use illegal words in the question title. And don't try to push them in with altered spellings!

Comment: Sorry. Changed. It was an error message.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and not only I. Please see: 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+Ryangocal/posts/9vQv8HYwwdC

Comment: Also make sure the emulator you are using is the one with Google APIs

Comment: And check this one also: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/201 
Check that you are using the correct Sha1

Comment: It seems it is not working anymore ! Even on older apps using it for a long time it doesn't work... :/ if anyone can find a solution to this that would be helpful !

Comment: Its broken. Even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I am into this since yesterday. Even if we perform all steps still it gives this error. Unable to find any solutions. I am stuck here. Can somebody please resolve this?

Comment: @braz I am also facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @ZainAli didn't. looks like it's really not working now. it's not necessary for me now so I've stopped tries to find any solution.

Comment: @jcesarmobile maybe you add it to answers. I'll mark your answer as correct

Comment: @Joao deleted the other one and added the answer here as this was created earlier. Will vote to close the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reported the problem on the Google Issue tracker and they have closed it as won't fix stating that it's deprecated

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73993857

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code below :

```
mPlusOneButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new OnPlusOneClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {
        if(!plusClient.isConnected()) {
            plusClient.connect();
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

and also see this activity in `android-sdk` for reference :

```
androidsdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/plus/src/com/google/android/gms/samples/plus/PlusOneActivity.java
```

Comment: plusClient deprecated