# Error while implementing google plus one button

Tags: android, google-plus-one

I am trying to implement PlusOneButton of google. I have created the project in developer console and generated SHA1 key using my keystore for debug type. I then added that SHA1 key and generated the client id. 
After that I added the PlusOneButton as mentioned in the doc https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend. When I click on the button I get this error [image]

I have few doubts do I need to add the client id somewhere or add client_secret.json though it is not mentioned anywhere.

edit : 
Here is the code I am using

```
  <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
    android:id="@+id/google_plus_one_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    plus:size="standard"
    plus:annotation="inline" 
    />



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        googlePlusView = findViewById(R.id.google_plus_one_button);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
        googlePlusView.initialize(URL, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Why is this question down voted. I have looked at many places but could not find the solution.

Comment: You should add the code!

Comment: Looks like it's a google problem, I'm facing this problem too and found some similar questions

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052258/1351469 TLDR, they have deprecated it but didn't update the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google +1 button error on android app there was a temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748557/google-1-button-error-on-android-app-there-was-a-temporary)

Comment: @jcesarmobile So it means that we cannot use Google +1 button now. So I should just open the google + page in webview. Or is there any other way I can ask user to do +1 on my google plus page?